# How to get the full URL of the route?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a Sinatra [template file](https://github.com/dpisarenko/50web/blob/songcontest1/views/songcontest/home.erb), which sends a POST request to the [route](https://github.com/dpisarenko/50web/blob/songcontest1/routes/songcontest.rb) `/en/signup` (`en` is the locale).

I need to extract the `en` from `/en/signup`. I tried to use `request.path` in the following code, but contains only `/signup`, not `/en/signup`. The log file shows that `/en/signup` was called.

What construct can I use in the route `post '/signup'` in order to get `/en/signup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That solved my problem: `redirect to('/' + I18n.locale.to_s + '/signup-success')`.

Answer (score 1):

Wake up, Neo.

From [`route`](https://github.com/dpisarenko/50web/blob/songcontest1/routes/songcontest.rb#L37) file:

```
before '/:locale/*' do
  I18n.locale       =       params[:locale]
  request.path_info = '/' + params[:splat ][0]
end
```

Comment: So how do I get the locale (`en`, `de`, `ru`) in the `signup` route?

Comment: seems to me that it is set to `I18n.locale` just as in your view. (lets hope you don't run more than one thread!)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use java:

```
var url = document.URL;
var pieces = url.split("/");
```

Then simply split where and when you need to. The variable `pieces` is an array. For further splitting use `pieces = pieces[1` (or others) `].split("/` (or others `");`

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hello Sir if you use php try the code below. it will get the full path of the url for instance /example/en/signup.

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Answer (score 0):

In Addition you can get including the http host (localhost) try the code below

$output =  "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

echo $output;